# ypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'digest') when using Nuxt.js auth

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

## Description

I'm encountering a TypeError when trying to use the Nuxt.js auth module in my project. The error message I'm seeing is "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'digest')". It occurs when I click the "Login" button, which triggers the validate method.

This only happens when the app is deployed on a remote server.

The app is severed on static with nginx and the auth server is on the same server behind the nginx proxy.

## code

```js
<template>
  <v-btn
    color="success"
    class="mr-4"
    @click="validate"
  >
    Login
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'IndexPage',

  methods: {
    validate() {
      this.$auth.loginWith('oidc');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

## nuxt.config.js

```
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

export default {
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      oidc: {
        scheme: 'openIDConnect',
        clientId: 'test',
        endpoints: {
          configuration: 'http://<host>/auth/realms/test/.well-known/openid-configuration',
        },
 /*       responseType: 'code',
        grantType: 'authorization_code',
        scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
        codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',*/
      }
    }
  },
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,

  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - sample',
    title: 'sample',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
  ],

  // Vuetify module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```